# How do I make this cash register program output the total cost and individual costs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a cash register program that does that following:

Prints the name 
Prints the date 
Uses a function(most important) 
Prints out the individual cost of each item 
Prints out the total cost

You can make your own, or just make adjustments to mine:

```
def cash(item1, item2, *items3): 
   sum = item1 + item2 
   for number in items3: 
      sum = sum + number 
   return sum 

print('Here is your final purchase:') 
print('\nJoe') 
print('06/20/17') 
print('\nYour total is:\n') 
cash(20,1,29)
```

I have no idea what I'm doing. This is a giant project and I really need help. THANKS

(BTW: Use of inputs are optional, feel free to add them if you'd like)

Comment: Please do not routinely tag questions with the editor/IDE used.

Comment: Side-note: Don't name variables the same thing as Python built-in functions/types. If you actually need the `sum` function at some point in the `cash` function, you'd get a rude surprise telling you that `int` (or `float`) is not callable (because you shadowed the built-in function `sum` with a local variable containing a number). Particularly appropriate since your whole `cash` function could simplify to `def cash(item1, item2, *items3): return sum(items3, item1 + item2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def cash_register(items, todaysdate, name):
    print(name.capitalize() + ", " + todaysdate + "\n\n)
    totalcost = 0.00
    for i in items:
        cost = items[i]
        print(str(i.title()) + ": $" + str(cost))
        totalcost += cost
    print("Total cost: $" + str(totalcost))
```

This function takes a dictionary as an argument, with the item name as the key and the cost as the value, like the following:
`cash_register({"item":0.00, "item2": 1.00})`. Make sure not to put a dollar sign with the cost.

Comment: Nice answer; just not to this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `cash`, which calculates the total, but you don't do anything with the value it returns (for example, print it).

Comment: Thanks! And how do you print the individual cost of each item?

Comment: `cash` knows the cost of each item (it has to in order to sum them up).